# Javascript "like" function against array

Tags: javascript

I have read the other items on stack overflow, and so far, none work or possibly i do not understand them.

I would like for a user to be able to Type a value into a field, this looks through each item within my array and then returns the items which match.

here is an example of the array.

```
[{
"ID": 249,
"SetNumber": 7993,
"URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4516696.pdf",
"Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4516696.png",
"Description": "Service Station",
"Notes": "BUILD.INSTR.3006,  7993 NA 2/2",
"DashedNumber": "7993-1"
 },
 {
"ID": 250,
"SetNumber": 7994,
"URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4516447.pdf",
"Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4516447.png",
"Description": "LEGO City Harbor",
"Notes": "BUILD.INSTR.3006, 7994 2/3",
"DashedNumber": "7994-1"
 },
 {
"ID": 251,
"SetNumber": 7994,
"URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4516451.pdf",
"Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4516451.png",
"Description": "LEGO City Harbor",
"Notes": "BUILD.INSTR.3006, 7994 3/3",
"DashedNumber": "7994-1"
 }]
```

So the client could type in Lego, and the second two would be shown.

here is my code so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#search-now').click(function () {
    var newArray = obj.results.filter(function (el) {
        return el.ID &&
            el.SetNumber &&
            el.Images &&
            el.URL &&
            el.Description == $('#dynamId').val() &&
            el.Notes &&
            el.DashedNumber;

    });
```

but this only returns exact matches not "like" matches.

Comment: for that to happen you should use indexOf() not ==

Comment: I believe that you can use a fuzzy search algorithm. For example [https://fusejs.io/](https://fusejs.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `indexOf` and `toLowerCase` (if case insensitive) instead of just `==`.

**Example** (uses [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) `filter` method; can be interchanged with your find method)

```js
let legoProducts = [{
    "ID": 249,
    "SetNumber": 7993,
    "URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4516696.pdf",
    "Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4516696.png",
    "Description": "Service Station",
    "Notes": "BUILD.INSTR.3006,  7993 NA 2/2",
    "DashedNumber": "7993-1"
 },
 {
    "ID": 250,
    "SetNumber": 7994,
    "URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4516447.pdf",
    "Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4516447.png",
    "Description": "LEGO City Harbor",
    "Notes": "BUILD.INSTR.3006, 7994 2/3",
    "DashedNumber": "7994-1"
 },
 {
    "ID": 251,
    "SetNumber": 7994,
    "URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4516451.pdf",
    "Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4516451.png",
    "Description": "LEGO City Harbor",
    "Notes": "BUILD.INSTR.3006, 7994 3/3",
    "DashedNumber": "7994-1"
 }];

let searchString = 'Lego';
let result = _.filter(legoProducts, function(object) {
 return object.Description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) != -1;
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this issue by doing

```
el.Description.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#dynamId').val().toLowerCase()) !== -1
```

IndexOf scans the string and returns the index at which it finds the match. Lowercasing everything so that the search is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` operator matches for exact. To match `like`, you'll need to use `||` operator.

But testing properties without any values will return true until it's not undefined or falsy values. So, you'll need to test for some value if you want to verify for eg.

```
return el.ID == 56 || el.SetNumber == 234 ...
```

Without testing for values, you're going to match which actually have truthy values like:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 23,
    "SetNumber": 53
   },
   {
    "SetNumber": 78
   }
]
.filter(function(el) {
   return el.ID;
})
```

This will match the first object in the example since second object in this array has no ID property defined.

Although, it seems a vague approach. I will suggest you to check it with a value like:

```
return typeof el.ID !== 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular expression, like `new Regex('. *'+$('#dynamId').val()+'. *')` instead of `==` operator and use the match method against the field you're interested to.

Comment: Dynamic regexes require escaping of its parameters